# Calculating expected value of 3 dice

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm having a little trouble with calculating the expected value. So in my question, I can roll $3$ dice and I make $\$100$ for every value.
E.g. If I role $(1,2,3) = 1 + 2 + 3= 6$, so I'd make $\$600$.
Not sure how to calculate the expected value?

Comment: What did you try? Do you know how to calculate the expected value of one dice?

Comment: What is the expected value for one dice?

Comment: So I got E(X) = 3.5 for one dice. Do I just go 3.5*3 then for 3 dice?

Answer (score 1):

Since $E(D_6) = 3.5$ for a single dice roll, by linearity,

$$E(D_6 + D_6 + D_6) = 3 \cdot E(D_6) = 10.5 \implies \boxed{\$1050} $$